# Remove items from a list in linq that contain the whole phrase c#

Tags: c#, lambda

I hope this is a quick question.  I have a list of items with a "path" property. I use the following line:

```
docReturnResult.RemoveAll(x => !x.DocumentPath.Contains(library));
```

This does remove the items I need, however I am running into a problem.  If the value for library is "Non Archive" and I have two items in the docReturnResult list, one with "/Non Archive/" and another with "/Archive/" in the path, it remove both.  I just want to remove the item that doesn't match the whole value of library, so I only want "/Archive/" to be removed not both.  How can I specify the exact value?

Thanks.

Comment: It shouldn't be removing both. If the value of `library` were `Archive`, then I could see both being removed.

Comment: I think you meant lambda expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are looking for

```
 docReturnResult.RemoveAll(x => !x.DocumentPath.Equals(library));
```

The reason I am using Equals and not == is that == is a reference check, asking if the obejct is the same reference.
Where the "Equals" only validates the values of the object.
So two different object references with the same content would still be equal in equals, the == operator, would return false, as the reference identifier is not identical. 
If I am wrong, I am sure someone has a better explanation than me :)

UPDATE:

Provided that it's only determining part of the path itself, 
I would split the entire path with the Split function on '/'
and then check if library is equal to any of the values in the resulting array.

gimme a second, I have to load up visual studio to actually debug if the split does what I expect in linq :)

UPDATE 2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                string one = "http://<site>/Non Archive/<document>";
                string two = "http://<site>/Archive/<document>";
                char delimiter = '/';
                List<string> list = new List<string> { one, two };
                string target = "Archive";

                foreach (string s in list)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("after remove");

                list.RemoveAll(x => x.Split(delimiter).ToList().Any(y => y.Equals(target)));

                foreach (string s in list)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }


                Console.ReadLine();

            }
```

This does what I meant to say. I understand you already fixed it. But still, this might guide others with a similar problem.

Results:[image]

Comment: You *are* wrong. [`String` overloads the `==` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_equality\(v=vs.110\).aspx) to provide value-type semantics for equality check.

Comment: 1. `==` uses `String.Equals(s1,s2)` which doesn't compare references only 2. This answer doesn't help because OP is decribing a problem that isn't reproducible

Comment: @MatthewWatson
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/difference-between-operator-and-equals-method-in-C-Sharp/

I haven't reproced this myself to test, but it looks legit.

Comment: @TimSchmelter where does his example state that this will always be strings? 
you might be justified in inferring it, but there is no type specification in his example. 
it simply displays an object "library". why can't that object be of type object? Why does it have to be string?

Comment: @TimSchmelter no no, you are inferring it is about strings. As in the example he might very well be comparing a list of objects. He doesn't specify this. You simply assume he does. Look at the question. Really look. He is talking about the value. But never mentions the word string. Not even once. He very clearly speaks about "Value of" the object named library. But doesn't actually say string. Nor does he tag it with a string tag. It's all based on the assumption that it is a tag he is talking about.

Comment: @MortenBork: ok, now i've got it. But for me `"Non Archive"` is clearly a string :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter but we can agree that this question is horribly stated. He could have been a lot clearer in asking it :)

Comment: The full path returned may be "http://<site>/Non Archive/<document>" for one item and the next may be "http://<site>/Archive/<document>"  If I want to remove the "Non Archive" item and not the "Archive" item, when I pass in the linq expression docReturnResult.RemoveAll(x => !x.DocumentPath.Contains(library)); and library = "Non Archive" then both items are removed.

Comment: How could I have asked it more clear?  I wrapped the strings I was looking for in quotes to indicate they are strings I am looking for.

Comment: Hi John. 
1, Include type definitions for all values. 
2, Clearly show used input and expected output.
3, Include results of already try executions of the code.
4, enough code to actually replicate the problem.

And now that you have stated categorically that it is strings, == and equals are basically the same.

Comment: Also John I have updated my answer with a suggestion to fix your issue.

Comment: @MortenBork thanks for the response.  I should have been more clear on that.  It appears the problem was that the string value for library was being passed in URLEncoded so the string value was not "Non Archive" but "Non+Archive" with a "+" for spaces.  Once I stripped out the Url Encoding, the contains worked.  So it appears that "+" was saying look for both of these values or one of these values.

Comment: Hi John. I just updated the answer here for a clear undestanding of what I meant, also in the quality of the code provided for a question. 

you can basically copy paste the code of the second update into a console project, and presto, demonstrate what I meant with something. As I would have like to be able to do directly from your question. 

See how much information I have to infer to replicate the results you are requesting, and how much I might actually have gotten it wrong simply from my hasty read etc.

Comment: @RufusL which part is incorrect? It is genrally true. There is an exception for strings true, but if you read the original question, that is still not expained. You actaully have to go through the comments to know this. And then you also know what the correct answer is.
Until the auther modifies his question, it is still very much debateable if he is talking about strings. If he modifies his question, I will modify my answer.
It would be better actually, if he included his original code attempt in the question.

Comment: @MortenBork I meant the part where you say, *"`==` is a reference check"*, because that's not true for strings.

Comment: @RufusL That is an absolutely correct statement, its a rule with 1 exception. And the exception is stipulated in the comments.

Comment: @MortenBork The question is about strings, though. The `.Contains` method belongs to the `string` class (if it was a `List<T> Contains`, the problem wouldn't exist in the first place). If someone really wanted to be pedantic about it, then they might argue that the question could be about value types, which also means no reference check. Your statement is only true if the objects are non-string reference types that haven't overridden the operator. I understand you're trying to help the OP, but your answer could be improved by modifying that statement (and possibly linking to the documentation)

Comment: @RufusL
1, I have linked to a demonstration, that has been qouted, and contains the correct definitions. So No need to link to anything further.
2, The list <T> could contain any object. It could f.eks be an array of chars, 
It could in fact be any object type, as I have stated before, his example has no type definitions in it at all. note he just attempts to find if an instance of any type exists within a property that is also not known.
Contains can be used for any object in a list of any objects. So your assertion that this renders the question invalid, is simply incorrect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177226/discussion-between-morten-bork-and-rufus-l).